# details view with Dropdownn control

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

in the modal pop up  i am  using detailsview control   by default all the data  would
 be   shown in label. 
 there  will be an edit button down once the user  clicks  edit button  all the lablel  would be  gone and text box and  dropdown control  should be  present  so that user  can  change the  values and again update into database

looking forward  for a  solution. i dnt want to use **sqlDatasource**. i wanted  it  to do in .cs
 thank you

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: what is issue you are getting? not clear your qustion

Answer (score 1):

here is how to:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>


protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {

            ddl.DataSource = dataSource;
            ddl.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```